# How to deploy compiled contract on chain?

Tags: contract-deployment, bsc

I have compiled my contract using solc. Now i have 2 files file.bin and file.evm. How to deploy them on bsc chain? Is this even possible to deploy compiled contract?

Comment: Ethers.js has a deploy function. Also there is a toolkit called hardhat, which can deploy for you as well.

Comment: I'd suggest to use a tool like hardhat, truffle, embark to help you deploy and test smart contracts.